# Xamarin forms image import to new page

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to import an camera/Gallary image into a page, not into the `App()` page, the function `ShouldTakePicture()` doesn't work, can anyone provide a sample code where I can import image to another page and display in a listview?

This import image was done form code in the link http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#camera

However when doing in another page, the MainActivity throws bellow error

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Gallary2.Injury' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Application'    Gallary2.Droid  C:\Users\haris\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gallary2\Gallary2\Gallary2.Droid\MainActivity.cs   32  Active`

can anyone help me with image import demo project in Xamarin Forms? (Only c# please, we are not making changes in XAML )

Comment: using the Media Plugin for Forms is much easier - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created a new page and in that new page you created a `ShouldTakePicture` property of type `Action`. The reason that the code is now failing, is because of this line in the iOS and Android projects:

```
(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App).ShouldTakePicture += () => {
```

That line is expecting the `ShouldTakePicture` property to be in your `App` class, but it has been moved to your new page.

To fix this, you could either move that property back into your `App` class and then reference it from your new page by calling `Command = new Command(o => App.ShouldTakePicture()),`.

A better way to fix this would be to use Xamarin's `DependencyService`, info about that is [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/). If you need help setting up the `DependencyService`, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, while trying the above i am getting an error

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'App.ShouldTakePicture' Gallary2 C:\Users\haris\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gallary2\Gallary2\Gallary2\Injury.xaml.cs 23 Active


can you please suggest a way to resolve this?

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non-static field", this is issues i am unable to resolve, thanks for your help

Comment: @HarishVelala I am assuming you went with the option to move the property back into the `App` class. So it sound like you either need to declare the `ShouldTakePicture()` method as static or you need to initialize an instance of the `App` class which means you would have to do this: `App app = new App(); app.ShouldTakePicture();`